# How to use ensureIndex in MongoDB Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working with Mongo 2.6.0. How do I use the ensureIndex functionality on a collection? Currently it shows me as deprecated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume since you say you're using 2.6 of the server, you're using 2.12 of the Java driver?  If you look at the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html), where the `ensureIndex` methods are deprecated it tells you which method you should use instead - you should be using `createIndex`.